# Specific Meaning of $\sum_k |\nabla_{\mathbf{p}_k} C_i |^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to implement what this following paper is talking about: https://mmacklin.com/pbf_sig_preprint.pdf

The following formula (9) confuses me:

$$
\lambda_i = -{C_i(\mathbf{p}_1, \dots, \mathbf{p}_n) 
\over 
\sum_k |\nabla_{\mathbf{p}_k} C_i |^2} 
$$

Specifically the denominator section. Does that section by itself mean that I:

1. Take the gradient $∇ p_k$ and multiply it by $C_i$,
2. Find the length/magntide of this gradient,
3. Raise the result to the power of 2,
4. And repeat this for all of $_k$? and sum them all together?

Comment: Isn't $\Delta_{p_{k}} C_{i}$ just the usual notation for partial gradient of $C_{i}$ in the variable $p_{k}$? So it looks like the denominator is just length square of the total gradient.

Comment: @calcstudent That seems very, very likely actually!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\nabla_{\mathbf{p}_k} C_i$ ist defined in Equation 8.

It is a vector itself ($p_k$ is a position vector), so the absolute value signs around it are used to denote the Euclidean norm.